# Object.GetType() method thread safety

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-core, thread-safety

Based on [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object?view=net-6.0#thread-safety) it seems that instance methods defined in the [`System.Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object?view=net-6.0) type are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

This basically means that, given any type instance, it is **not** safe to call the [`GetType()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gettype?view=net-6.0) method concurrently from different threads.

Is this true even for a type that **I do know** it is actually thread safe (based on documentation or known type implementation) ?

For instance consider the [ImmutableList<T> class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablelist-1?view=net-6.0). This type is [documented to be thread safe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablelist-1?view=net-6.0#thread-safety), so I would expect I can use any instance of this type concurrently from multiple threads in a safe way, even when calling the `GetType()` method.

Another example is a stateless service class used inside an ASP.NET core application: a steteless class is thread safe by design (because there is no state to mess up when working concurrently on a class instance). So, again in this case, I expect **no** issues in using the same instance concurrently from multiple threads, even when calling the `GetType()` method.

In both these cases can I assume that **it is actually safe** to call the `GetType()` method concurrently from different threads ?

### How did I get to asking myself this question ?

While working with an ASP.NET core application I registered a few stateless services as singleton dependencies and I happened to call `GetType()` on one of them.
Web applications are multi thread by nature, so I asked myself about the safety of doing this from multiple threads concurrently.

### Why this seems confusing to me ?

The main point is that `Object.GetType()` is **not** a `virtual` method, so each type gets the implementation **directly from the `System.Object` class**. That's why I checked the documentation of [`System.Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object?view=net-6.0) class itself, even though I was working with a class thread safe by design (being stateless).

### What I intuitively think about this

The type information for an object can't change after the object has been created, so **intuitively** there is no mutable state related with it, so I do **not** expect any issue in calling `GetType()` on the same object instance from different threads at the same time.

This kind of assumption is purely based on intuition and, sometimes, stuff are counter-intuitive. Apart from that, the Microsoft docs [explicitly states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object?view=net-6.0#thread-safety) that thread safety is **not** guaranteed for any instance method of `System.Object`, so the topic of this question makes sense to me.

Comment: As an object's type cannot change, I would assume that GetType() is thread-safe. But there is probably no formal guarantee.

Comment: @KlausGütter as pointed out in my last edits to the question, based on intuition, I agree with you. I can't see any mutable state related with the type information of any type instance because, based on my knowledge, in .NET there is no way to change the type of an object after the object has been created.

Comment: The problem here is that that's the standard disclaimer on practically all classes that have a thread safety section in their documentation. Unless someone has gone through and especially considered the specific class under discussion, that's what you get to see. We all know that this specific situation is thread safe but there's not some secret second-level set of documentation that we're going to uncover for you, so there's not going to be a more definitive answer.

Answer (score 0):

GetType is a pure method, which means it does not change/mutate state so is inherently thread safe. This is visible in the reference source for [Object.cs](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/object.cs) that has the [Pure] attribute.

Comment: This is not sufficient to be sure that GetType is thread-safe. While the method is guaranteed to not change any visible state, other methods called in parallel might do so and this could theoretically break thread-safety of GetType().

Comment: I have never used the [Pure] attribute and I wasn't aware of it. Based on my understanding it is related with the idea of pure function and side effects. I'm not sure it is strictly related with the idea of thread safety, but again intuitively there is a relationship because no side effects usually implies thread safety.

Comment: @KlausGütter maybe we're talking definitions now, but something is generally thread safe if it's safe to use accross multiple threads without corrupting state. You're saying other functions aren't thread safe and therefore GetType isn't?